# How do I convert a date timestamp in oracle to a date?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, datetime, format

I'm looking to convert (using Oracle) a date timestamp
[2018-01-25T00:00:00.000+00:00] to a date [2018-01-24].  I've tried several formats however I can't seem to find the right one to convert it.  I'm unsure of how to handle the +00:00.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you really ask.

It you have a real Oracle `timestamp` and you want a string in format `'YYYY-MM-DD'`, you can use  `to_char()`:

```
select to_char(col, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as res from mytable
```

If you have a *string* in ISO timestamp format, and you want a string as a result:

```
select substr(col, 1, 10) as res from mytable
```

If you have a `timestamp` column and you want to set the time portion to `00:00:00`:

```
select trunc(col) as res from mytable;
```

This returns a value of datatype `date`.

Comment: Tried the to_char(col, 'YYYY-MM-DD') and that threw an error.  More specifically it said "oracle.xdo.XDOException: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01481: invalid number format model".  Tried the 2nd one with the substr however that left the data coming out unchanged.  The 3rd one I tried with trunc(col) also rendered the same unchanged output..

Comment: @Dale: what is the datatype of that column?

Comment: @GMB - Ahh.. Got it.  Typo on the column name.  the 3rd one did the trick.  Thanks!

Comment: The comment on the 3rd option is wrong; if you use `TRUNC` then [the value returned will have the `DATE` data type](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions201.htm) and not the `TIMESTAMP` data type.

Comment: Still works for me however I do appreciate the correction.